# How to generate server code from an OpenAPI Specification (OAS) in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi, code-generation, contract-first

I'm working on a Django Rest Framework project, and I have an OpenAPI Specification (OAS) file that I'd like to use for code generation. My goal is to automatically generate API endpoints, serializers, and views from this OAS file.

I'm seeking guidance on how to generate Django Rest Framework code (serializers, views, URLs) based on the OAS file. I'd like to know which tools or libraries are commonly used for this purpose and any steps or configurations I need to follow. Additionally, any tips or best practices for integrating OAS with Django Rest Framework would be greatly appreciated.

I've read through the documentation for Django Rest Framework and searched for relevant resources online, but I haven't found a clear path for integrating OAS with Django Rest Framework.

Thank you for any guidance or suggestions you can provide!

https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0

Comment: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5448